# How to dynamically provide T .. class ObjectXMLSerializer<T> where T : class

Tags: c#, .net

Ok so the class I want to use is declared with:

```
public static class ObjectXMLSerializer<T> where T : class
```

I have many objects that I want to serialize, but I do not know their "class"

```
object myclass = new MyNamespace.MyClass() as object;
```

How do I do the following... ?

```
ObjectXMLSerializer< ? >.Save(myclass,"output.xml");
```

I can't do this because the type that is expected, is "class"

```
ObjectXMLSerializer< myclass.GetType() >.Save(myclass,"output.xml");
```

And this just wouldnt work ...

```
ObjectXMLSerializer< object >.Save(myclass,"output.xml");
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Comment: "And this just wouldnt work ..." - in what way?

Comment: That method doesnt work for the intended purpose, because object does not reflect the structure of the original object

Comment: That's not really very descriptive. Something which shows the desired output and the actual output would be rather more helpful. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use generics if XML serialization is all that you care about:

```
public static class ObjectXMLSerializer { 
  public static void Save(object objectToSerialize, string fileName) { 
    // ...
  } 
}
```

Alternatively, look at the [`XmlSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) class, it might already cover your requirements:

```
public static class ObjectXMLSerializer {
  public static void Save(object objectToSerialize, string fileName) {
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(objectToSerialize.GetType());
    using (var stream = File.OpenWrite(fileName)) {
      serializer.Serialize(stream, objectToSerialize);
    }
  }
}
```

To deserialize, though, since you *must* know the compile-time type of the object that you want, you could use generics on the deserialization method:

```
public static class ObjectXMLDeserializer {
  public static T Load<T>(string fileName) { 
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    using (var stream = File.OpenRead(fileName)) {
      return (T)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: These two functions make pretty decent extention methods as well.

Comment: @asawyer: absolutely! Take a look at [this post](http://codecrafter.blogspot.com/2010/02/c-quasi-mixins-pattern.html) for a different take on this subject.

Answer (score 7):

You're trying to use generics for something it isn't designed for.

Generics are meant to give *compile-time* safety (and express information about the API at compile-time). You don't know the types involved at compile-time, so you've got a problem.

Options:

- Use a non-generic API
- Call the generic API via reflection
- Redesign your code so that the relevant method *does* know the type at compile-time (e.g. make the method that *calls* `Save` generic too)

Comment: I am requesting a new feature on SO. A begrudging upvote button. One that implies "Curses! I shake my fist at you Jon Skeet!" -- All in good fun though.

Comment: Thanks Jon, especially for such a quick and precise response!

Answer (score 1):

You could try this without generics:

```
public static class ObjectXMLSerializer
{
    public static void Save(IXmlSerializable myObject, string fileName) 
    {
        // whatever
    }
}
```

Although, depending on what you're trying to do, you might be better off just using the framework's `XmlSerializer` instead of writing your own.

Comment: An object doesn't need to implement IXmlSerializable to be serialized to XML... this interface is used only to provide custom XML serialization

Comment: @Thomas: Absolutely. But I figured it would be an easy way to narrow down the scope of objects that could be passed to this method. It'd probably be best replaced by a custom interface if the OP goes that route.

Answer (score 0):

I'm recommending an interface `IXmlSerializable` with the method `Serialize()` exposed. If you need to refer to them generically (without knowing it's ClassA or ClassB , you can cast or box them to the interface and call the method.

Usually, I just attribute my objects with `Serializable` and make sure all the properties are serializable or attribute the property with `XmlIgnore` / `Nonserialized`

```
[Serializable]
public class MyClass
{
     [Nonserialized]
     private DataTable _myProperty;
     [XmlIgnore]
     public DataTable MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Despite the fact that you might be doing it wrong, you can construct a generic type and an instance of generic type using reflection. For example, if I would like to create a `List<int>` I can write

```
Type t = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(int));
object list = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
// add an integer to list and get Count property        
t.GetMethod("Add").Invoke(list, new object[] {3});
int count = (int) t.GetProperty("Count").GetValue(list, null);
```

... and that is why everybody would suggest redesigning your class.